# Array.prototype.splice in Chrome - not conforming to spec?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've just found a slip in my code while copying an array. I did `array.splice(0)`, rather than using `slice`. But strangely it still works. This usage isn't compliant with the [Array.prototype.splice spec on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) which states that the `deleteCount` (second argument) is mandatory and that it returns

"An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned. "

I've run some tests in Chrome and this is what I got

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var spliced = array.splice(0); // [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

But when I do

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var spliced = array.splice(0, 0); // [] as per the spec
```

Is this an interesting Chrome feature or is the spec out of date?

Comment: Maybe changing the title to "Expected result of `splice(0)` vs `splice(0, 0)`" would be more expressive? Not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12), one could argue `arr.splice(0)` and `arr.splice(0, 0)` should return the same result, because in step 7, `ToInteger(undefined)` is `0`.

> 7. Let *actualDeleteCount* be `min(max(ToInteger(deleteCount),0), len – actualStart`).

However, it's not clear if it is even valid to call `.splice` with a single argument.

[ECMAScript 6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.splice) has a special case for single arguments (and one for no arguments):

> 9. If the number of actual arguments is 0, then
>      Let *insertCount* be 0.
>      Let *actualDeleteCount* be 0.
> 10. Else if the number of actual arguments is 1, then
>       Let *insertCount* be 0.
>       Let *actualDeleteCount* be *len* - *actualStart*

`len` is the length of the array and `actualStart` is derived from the first argument. So `arr.splice(0)` becomes equivalent to `arr.splice(0, arr. length)`, which means Chrome seems to comply to the new spec (intentionally or unintentionally).

On the other hand, `arr.splice()` is equivalent to `arr.splice(0, 0)` and Chrome returns an empty array as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Had a look at ES5 but didn't think of checking the ES6 spec. Glad I found the error though, it's a Cordova app and will be running in a WebView so could have seen some bad behaviour!